# How to debug OnEdit event function in google sheets appscript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have worked in windows forms app C#, uwp apps. As far those are concerned, the debugging is quite easy, I put a breakpoint where I need to pause execution to see the current values of the variables where I put breakpoint, I check the values by either mouseover or using autos. But I am new to Sheets app script, and tried to find how to debug. but could not get. Here is by onEdit event function.

```
function onEdit(e) {      
    var range = e.range;
    // range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date());
    // range.setBackground("green");
    Logger.log("hello this is onEdit");

    if(range.getNumRows() === 1 && range.getNumColumns() === 1 ) 
    {      
        if (range.getValue = "Done")
        {
         range.setValue("Weekly");
        }
    }
}
```

I put this function inside code.gs under files section. It works well.
But If I put a breakpoint, and edit anywhere in the sheets, the breakpoint is not called.
If I click the 'Debug'(Debug the selected function) menu, the debugging works.
but the parameter e is not defined, since the OnEdit function is not called from sheets by cell edit.

I am clueless how to debug the onEdit function, by editing a cell ?

Comment: I just use `e.source.toast()` commands in different places to figure out what's going on.   But you can run it from another function by creating an event object which is pretty easy.

Comment: if you want to create an event object try running `function onEdit(e) {Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));}` and look at executions after editing and then you'll know what you need to create the event object.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `onEdit()` and you changes a value in spreadsheet, Apps Script will pass an event object to `onEdit()` function, typically called `e`. The event object contains information about the context that caused the trigger to fire.

The only way you can debug an event object is to print the value of `e` after an event was made. You can view each event by clicking the **Executions** tab of your Apps Script.

### Example:

Code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  Logger.log(e.range.getA1Notation());
}
```

Output:

[image]

### References:

- [Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Executions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dashboard#manage_executions)

Answer (score 2):

Just in case, here is the structure of an event object in SpreadsheetApp:

```
var e = {
    "authMode": {object},
    "range": {
      "columnStart": int,
      "rowStart": int,
      "rowEnd": int,
      "columnEnd": int
    },
    "source": {Spreadsheet_object},
    "oldValue": "string",
    "user": {
      "nickname": "string",
      "email": "string"
    },
    "value": "string"
  };
```

Comment: I don't think that will result in loading e.range with a Range Object

Comment: @Cooper , probably so. Nevertheless I'm using this structure as a simply short cheat-sheet pretty often. ) Congrats with 40.000, by the way!

Answer (score 0):

What might be helpful as an intermediate solution is create a dummy e(I think it's an object) in your function like call it from a dummy function.

```
function dummy()
{
  var dummye = [];  //create a temp value by executing Logger.log(e) in onEdit
  // and by executing once from actual sheet which will run onEdit(e) and print it.

  onEdit(dummye);
}

function onEdit(e) {    
    //Logger.log(e);  //take this value to create dummye
    
    var range = e.range;
    // range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date());
    // range.setBackground("green");
    Logger.log("hello this is onEdit");

    if(range.getNumRows() === 1 && range.getNumColumns() === 1 ) 
    {      
        if (range.getValue = "Done")
        {
         range.setValue("Weekly");
        }
    }
}
```